# How to wait for a grunt task to complete before running mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs, mocha.js

## In a nutshell...

I have some grunt tasks with external configs that I want to test (make sure they do what they're supposed to do). So I'd like to write a mocha test running the tasks in the `before` function and asserting everything went well.

## ...and with some details

In my `gruntfile` there is something like

```
# Load task configs from `grunt` dir.
configs = require('load-grunt-configs') grunt,
    config:
        src: ['tasks/*{.js,.json,.coffee,.cson}']

# Load all **grunt tasks** with patter `grunt-*`
require('load-grunt-tasks') grunt, pattern: [
    'grunt-*'
]

# Pass configs to grunt
grunt.initConfig configs
```

and afterwards some task registration...

However I now have access to my `less` task residing as a `less.cson` in my `tasks` folder 
(which uses `grunt-contrib-less`).

So far so good. :)

I'm using `chai` for assertions:

```
describe('Checking static resources for dev', function () {

    describe('less task', function () {

        before(function () {
            grunt.task.run('less');
        });

        it('should have a compiled css file for docs', function () {
            grunt.file.isFile('public/css/docs.css').should.be.ok;
            grunt.file.isFile('public/css/docs.css.map').should.be.ok;
        });
```

As expected, the task completes after the tests were run since it's not async and I don't know a way to tell grunt (without modifying the existing task/config) that it should call a possible `done` function when ready and **then** make the assertion.

I also tried `grunt-run-task` but could not manage to run any task (they abort with a timeout although I gave them more than 20 seconds to complete).

Guess I'm looking for something like

```
before(function (done) {
    grunt.task.run('less', done);
});
```

Anyone some advice?